# ALB Cognito integration - Id Token missing

Tags: amazon-cognito, openid-connect, aws-application-load-balancer

I have a spring boot application deployed as ECS service running behind an Application Load Balancer.
I am trying to use the ALB's built-in support for authentication with AWS Cognito User Pools.

*Even after authenticating the user successfully, the redirect request by the load balancer to the application endpoint does not include any OIDC tokens.
No id token and no access token.*

Here are the sequence of requests tracked with browser developer tools.

1. Request to "/authorize"

```
REQUEST :

GET
    https://dev.auth.example.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=ql98sh20guvkcktbkmb651so7&redirect_uri=https://app.example.com/oauth2/idpresponse&response_type=code&scope=openid&state=cMnSPDepIyWFnpPAUxPrwpDhn8dW2TWqkVOaBlXTKOXnEHIgBpcU++pPbKoR8EFG0f8J3ebyk9QLCUhvk95zhHKBaC89ZW2sLjKUOMvpVh0J3wUOD7KNNtou6Fwg86RX2UgKXp4o5kFMpCpqJE6e00wQ4Tfh2eOWxt5oT7hRPRJaRbrjlKFd/zDavWm4kg2lO/Vd4uRKpI8em69GivH9etFhfET5c6jF5GnliI25yqZEblxZkZNk9f/EuiM=
    
RESPONSE :

HTTP/2 302 Found
content-length: 0
location: https://dev.auth.example.com/login?client_id=ql98sh20guvkcktbkmb651so7&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fapp.example.com%2Foauth2%2Fidpresponse&response_type=code&scope=openid
&state=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

2. Request to GET "/login"

```
REQUEST :

    scheme : https
    host : dev.auth.example.com
    filename : /login
    client_id : ql98sh20guvkcktbkmb651so7
    redirect_uri : https://app.example.com/oauth2/idpresponse
    response_type : code
    scope : openid
    state : xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    
    
RESPONSE :
    HTTP OK. (Hosted Login UI displayed)
```

3. Request to POST "/login"

```
REQUEST :

    client_id : ql98sh20guvkcktbkmb651so7
    redirect_uri : https://app.example.com/oauth2/idpresponse
    response_type : code
    scope : openid
    state : xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    
    
RESPONSE :
    
    HTTP/2 302 Found
    content-length: 0
    location: https://app.example.com/oauth2/idpresponse?code=2a5b9b1d-06ea-4312-98be-f065ca4cd4ad&state=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    date: Fri, 30 Jun 2023 10:25:43 GMT
```

4. Request to /oauth2/idpResponse

```
REQUEST :

    GET 
    
    scheme : https
    host : app.example.com
    filename : /oauth2/idpresponse
    code : 2a5b9b1d-06ea-4312-98be-f065ca4cd4ad
    state : xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    
RESPONSE :

    HTTP/2 302 Found
    server: awselb/2.0
    date: Fri, 30 Jun 2023 10:25:43 GMT
    content-type: text/html
    content-length: 110
    location: https://app.example.com/home
    set-cookie: AWSELBAuthSessionCookie-0=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx; Expires=Fri, 07 Jul 2023 10:25:43 GMT; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
    set-cookie: AWSELBAuthSessionCookie-1=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx; Expires=Fri, 07 Jul 2023 10:25:43 GMT; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
```

5. Request to the API URL which originally triggered the authentication flow.

```
REQUEST

    GET
    
    scheme : https
    host : app.example.com
    filename : /home
    Address : 15.xxx.xxx.xxx:443
    
RESPONSE :

    Status : 401
    Unauthorized : VersionHTTP/2
    Transferred759 B (0 B size)
    Referrer Policystrict-origin-when-cross-origin


REQUEST HEADERS :

    GET /home HTTP/2

    Host: app.example.com
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/114.0
    Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
    Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
    Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
    Referer: https://dev.auth.example.com/
    Connection: keep-alive
    Cookie: AWSALBAuthNonce=PIGF4TiUMQH3XYfl; AWSELBAuthSessionCookie-0=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
    Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
    Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
    Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
    Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
    Pragma: no-cache
    Cache-Control: no-cache
```

I was expecting a Token Endpoint Request being issued between step 4 and 5.
Also the request to Application Endpoint (step 5) does not contain any Auth Tokens.

The fact that request to "/idpResponse" contains "ALBAuthSession" cookies indicates to me that the user was indeed authenticated successfully.
Using the traditional username/password for authentication (No MFA).

Any pointers on how to investigate this further please ?

Answer (score 1):

In this type of solution the token request, and a userinfo request, are taking place, in backend calls between the ALB and AWS Cognito, so you cannot trace them. The end to end flow is described [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/listener-authenticate-users.html).

A session cookie is then issued to browser clients. It is essentially a website model. Token information is available, but only to the backend application. The ALB forwards these in HTTP headers, as described in the above link.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Gary.

Looking at the link provided by you, 
 Step 9 says, 
 The Application Load Balancer validates the cookie and forwards the user info to targets in the X-AMZN-OIDC-* HTTP headers set. For more information, see User claims encoding and signature verification.
 
 This is exactly the issue I am facing. The redirect request to application endpoint does not contain any 'X-AMZN-OIDC-*' headers.

Comment: Ok, I think I understood it now. 
I have just created a servlet filter that simply prints all the incoming headers and I can see all x-amzn-oidc-* headers printed in the log. Thanks a lot for your guidance anyways.